# How to make JS load on every page change when using AngularJS/Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have removed turbolinks from application.js and I am working on an AngularJS project. In a form where I have some select2 dropdowns and some datetimepickers, the JS code doesn't load If I don't refresh the page.

I have also added data-no-turbolinks in my links (despite I disabled turbolinks) but the issue still occurs. I am working on development environment.

My JS file:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  // DateTime pickers for Start time, End time
  $(function () {
      $('#dtp_start_time').datetimepicker();
      $('#dtp_end_time').datetimepicker();
  });

  // Select2 box for search select boxes in Outage form
  $(".search_select").select2();

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
$(document).on('page:change', ready);
```

From my experience with Rails, loading JS in such ways is a pain, so how do I make it work ?

Comment: put this code in separate js file rather than putting any controller

Comment: @ShubhamNigam what do you mean ? It is in its own file and `//= require file.js` by application.js.